# Does Box-Cox need to be Reversed Prior to Running Model Evaluation?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, statsmodels

I am building an ARIMA  time series model using the Statsmodels package for Python.

As a part of my pipeline, I am doing Box-Cox transformation on the response variable (i.e. the series I am seeking to forecast).

Do I understand correctly that it is not necessary for me to reverse Box-Cox on my response variable prior to performing my model evaluation calculations (in this case we are using RMSE and MAPE)?

(I understand of course that I would need to reverse Box-Cox on any predictions coming out of the model.)

Comment: You don't *have* to evaluate your predictions at all. But if you do, I don't quite see how enlightening an evaluation of the transformed data would be. Especially if you want to compare different forecasts, which may be using different Box-Cox transformations.

Comment: There may be some problems with my terminology here.  Just to confirm . . . if I do Box-Cox on my response variable, train a model on training data and then want to do an RMSE against test data, are we saying that I need to reverse Box-Cox on both the test predictions and the test values PRIOR to calculating RMSE?  (My intuition was that I would been fine using transformed data as inputs to RMSE.)

Comment: I have only ever seen predictions evaluated after back-transformations. RMSE is hard enough to interpret; interpreting it on a transformed scale is even harder. Also, I have never seen the holdout data transformed. The workflow *invariably* is to transform the training data, fit a model, predict, back-transform the predictions, then compare these to (untransformed!) holdout data.

Comment: I'll follow the path you've proposed here - a big thank-you.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Hi Stephan, so say I trained my model on a Boxcox-ed y_train, and now I want to evaluate my prediction generated for X_test. Should I back-transform my prediction using the Lambda value I used to Boxcox y_train? (I am using the `inv_boxcox` from `scipy.special` to perform the back-transformation)

Comment: @Constantlyconfused: I would definitely backtransform, if only for interpretability. Note that this is not completely trivial, and you may get biases. I hope `inv_boxcox` gets this right. You might be having an unbiased forecast on the transformed scale, but get a bias after backtransformation if the backtransform was wrong (e.g., many people invert a log transform by simply exponentiating, which is wrong and yield a bias.)

Comment: This question is properly settled by considering your loss function, rather than by asserting any generalities about what is usually done or appealing to interpretability.  If you choose a Box-Cox transformation because it expresses the response in a more meaningful way than the original numbers, and you wish to minimize some measure of goodness of prediction in those terms, then you would keep the data transformed.  A standard scientific example (in chemistry and biology) is to express hydrogen ion concentrations in terms of their logarithms (Box-Cox parameter 0): that's the *pH,* of course.

Answer (score 1):

The process for ARIMA is to transform de data. Train the model, make prediction and reverse transform the data that has been predicted. If any other transformation has been made, like differentiation, you need to reverse transform your data in the reverse order that it was transformed before training your model.